# Issues with cloth simulation. How to turn off wind?

Tags: animation, rigging, cloth-simulation

I'm having several issues with cloth simulation. Trying to use it with two characters so I can render them and use them as sprites in a game. I've been messing around with all this settings for hours and I just can't seem to get it right...

**Issue with both characters:**

There's wind coming out of somewhere (moving the cloth) and I have no idea how to turn it off, never added any wind or anything. Even increased the gravity to -20 to see if that could make it heavier but the wind still affects it, and it still jiggles.

**Issue with the poncho character:**

I need to make the poncho heavier and nothing that I do affects that... the screenshots of the physics tab settings are from this character, the settings used for the gif. I need it to be a really heavy poncho, like those that make you sweat just from seeing someone wear them when it's not winter.

**Issue with the sword character:**

The cloth won't collide with the body (and yes, the body has the collision modifier turned on). I can't upload the file but I can provide you with screenshots and recordings, what do you need??

Please, I really need to fix this, any idea or recomendation for the settings is welcome. Or any other way of doing this that's fast and looks nice.

[image: settings1]  [image: settings2]  [image: longshot]  [image: ryoko]